# Вывод 2у-мерного ассоциатвного массива Php

Tags: php

Доброе время суток, некоторое время пытаюсь разобраться с ассоциативными массивами, искал информацию в интернете, но в силу моего кретинизма не могу применить методы их ввода и вывода на практике. Есть конкретное задание:

**Создайте массив, в котором будет не менее 3-х авторов и не менее 5-ти книг.
Необходимо вывести информацию по всем авторам, на каждой строке :

имя Автора – его email – год рождения.

Затем необходимо вывести информацию по книгам, на каждой строке:

Название книги – Имя автора - год выпуска книги.**

Пример:

*Николай Васильевич – gogol@gogol.ru - 1809
Пушкин – alexandr@sergeevich.ru - 1799
Мертвые души – Николай Васильевич - 1841
Вий – Николая Васильевич - 1834
Пиковая дама - Пушкин - 1833*

В моем понимании это выглядит  примерно так(книги просто следуют после авторов, ведь в задании ничего не сказано про особой порядок)

```
$AuthorsAndBooks= [ 'Николай В.Г. - ' => 
                    ['gogol@gogl.ru' => '1809'],
                    'Puskin A.S. - ' => 
                    ['alexandr@sergeevich.ru' => '1799']
                     'Lermontov - ' => 
                    ['lermontov@mihail.ru'=> 1814]
                   ];
```

И дальше мне хотелось бы узнать каким образом можно подряд вывести всю эту информацию в таком виде: Пиковая дама - Пушкин - 1833.

Очень хотелось бы почитать конкретные ответы, поэтому заранее прошу прощения и благодарю за любую оказанную помощь, в том числе за возможную литературу непосредственно для понимания работы с ассоциатвными массивами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается с помощью вложенного цикла

```
foreach($AuthorsAndBooks as $author => $books) {
    foreach($books as $book => $year){
        echo $author . $book . ' - ' . $year . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Николай В.Г. - gogol@gogl.ru - 1809
Puskin A.S. - alexandr@sergeevich.ru - 1799
Lermontov - lermontov@mihail.ru - 1814
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде такое же очевидное решение, как вложенный for, однако самому синтаксис подобрать не удалось(в меру своего кретинизма)